# Trouble installing MathNet.Numerics in VS2010 Express, System.Numerics is missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget-package, linear-regression

I'm new here, just getting my feet wet writing my first Windows Phone 7 app.  Specifically, I need to do linear regression on some data to get a simple y=Ax^2+Bx+C best fit curve.  After some searching I planned to use MathNet.Numerics, following the example I found.

However, in the NuGet package manager when I run:
PM> Install-Package MathNet.Numerics

the installation fails, with the following error:

Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Numerics'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

At line:1 char:16

- Install-Package <<<<  MathNet.Numerics

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : uGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I thought the first obvious step was to add System.Numerics to my project, but it does not exist in the "Add Reference" menu (or anywhere on my computer). I had thought it was included with .NET 4.0.  So I guess I have a few questions:

- Is my project configured incorrectly?
- Is there a more official way to download System.Numerics than www.dllme.com? Or is that a normal way to get official Microsoft packages?
- Or, does anyone have suggestions for a light math library that would do simple linear regression?  I suppose I could stop being lazy and just write it myself, but I would rather use one that I know is written correctly.

Thank you!

**Edit:**  So I've been kindly informed that System.Numerics does not exist for Windows phone.  I did some more searching and found this nicely written class to solve my problem, thought I'd throw the link up here in case anyone else finds it useful: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63170/Least-Squares-Regression-for-Quadratic-Curve-Fitti

I'm still a bit perplexed, as this official page seems to imply that MathNet.Numerics works great on Windows Phone.  I'd still be interested in getting that library working on a phone just to satisfy my curiosity:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304363(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: System.Numerics is available for a desktop app.  It is not going to be available on a phone.